# How to fix invalid initializer error while trying to create an array of pointers?

Tags: c, pointers

I am new in C programming and was trying to create an array of pointers with the below syntax, however it's giving error: invalid initializer

I have taken reference from many source in internet and found the following syntax there:

```
int myarr[10];
int *p[10] = &myarr;
```

Looking at the syntax and concept, it appears a very trivial case as I am encountering this at the beginning of learning pointers. However, not finding a correct way of fixing this to move ahead.
Kindly help.

Thanks.

Comment: `&myarr` is a pointer to an array (because `myarr` is an array). It is not an array of pointers, nor, more relevantly, a viable initializer for an array of pointers.  Are you sure you really want an *array* of pointers, as opposed to just one pointer?  Arrays of pointers certainly have uses, but it's unclear whether one would serve the particular use you have in mind.  If so then the details of the intended use affect how you might want to declare your array and set its elements.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I was referring to this link: https://www.javatpoint.com/c-pointers , under the heading "Pointer to array"  it gives the syntax and it failed during compilation. I read other sources to know what exactly it is and learnt that it p is an array of integer pointers. Pls let me know what is the intended action here with this kind of syntax and why it's failing ? Is this not array of pointers ? what is this then and how can I create array of pointers ?

Comment: Your code is failing because it is wrong.  The example you drew it from is also wrong.  They are wrong because a pointer to an array is not the same thing as an array of pointers, and more generally because an initializer for an array needs to be a brace-enclosed list of element initializers.  One way to fix it would be to drop the initializer part of the declaration of `p`.  Whether that's a *good* way to solve the problem depends, again, on what you plan to do with `p`, including whether the type declared for it is in fact the one you really want it to have.

Comment: @John Bollinger Got it, thanks!